# How to implement quick fixes and see all the parameter options for an overloaded function in neovim with nvim-jdtls

Tags: java, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

Basically there are two things stopping me from leaving intellij behind and using neovim for java development

1. The option to show quick fixes for the current line if it has an error
2. The option to see all the options for parameters for an overloaded function when hovering it

Thank you in advance

Comment: just curious: have you found any answers?